# Flink CEP and events order

Tags: apache-flink, flink-cep

I am new to Flink and Flink CEP. When working with Event Time, does Flink CEP iterates the events to check patterns in ascending (event-)time order or not?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when working with event time, Flink's CEP library sorts the events by their timestamps. It uses the watermarks to know when events can safely be considered ready for processing.

Comment: Thanks a lot!

So, let me be more specific.
1) At the beginning, I have a datastream of events.
1.1) I assignTimestampsAndWatermarks with BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor
1.2) I make this datastream a keyed datastream
1.3) I apply pattern() and select() and result in a new datastream.

Now I want to apply again pattern() and select() to get another datastream.
Q1: Is it needed again to apply steps 1.1 and 1.2 in order FlinkCEP to run with Event Time and sort my new events in ascending Event Time order?

Comment: Q2: If YES, what if I didn't do that. How Flink CEP would work? Would It use Process Time? With what order would Flnik CEP access the new event?

Comment: I believe the stream resulting from the PatternSelectFunction will have timestamps and watermarks, and so everything should just work.

Comment: The thing is that I combine events with timestamps (starting and ending time of trips) to extract events with ranges (time range of trips). Next, I want to detect events across different trips (trips with overlapping time ranges).

Comment: 1) Assign assignTimestampsAndWatermarks getting starting time of each trip
(This way I think that I will get the trips sorted by ascending starting time, am I right?)  2) Now, for each trip (t1), I have to seek for other overlapping trips that have started before t1 ended.

Does this solution sound you good? Can it be optimized?